# Where is the feed for a user's recent questions?

Tags: support, questions, feed

I am sure I saw someone pointing that there is a feed similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/48465/recent, but that gets only the questions. I believe it had an .html in the url, and it was hosted by SO itself. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?userid=48465&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=newest

Increase `pagesize` to put all questions on one page.

**Update**: Apparently there is a JSON option too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.json?userid=48465&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=newest

Comment: Where in the hell did that come from? I've never seen the `api` folder!

Comment: that's it, unfortunately it isn't a feed as I expected =( nothing that a Yahoo Pipe can't solve

Comment: It's used as the datasource for the tabs in the profiles. Check the href's :) Or disable javascript and try to go to page 2 of your questions :)

Comment: i find it funny when dynamic content is served by an url with .html extension

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.json?userid=48465&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=newest

Comment: Nice find, Brad.

Comment: I just figured that flair works that way, why not the API.

Comment: Good thinking. I'm fairly confident that it's rather difficult to keep things like this from leaking out with a community of curious developers :)